# How to regenerate an iPhone Xcode info.plist file

Tags: iphone, xcode, plist

I have moved my iPhone app from one machine to another.  In the process my info.plist file seems to have a bad bundle identifier and is not working.  I want to create an entirely new info.plist file for my project.

How can I do this?

Comment: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-13-missing-info.plist/

Comment: for new swiftUI projects, it's actually not required any more. everything is in the project configuration

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a clean info.plist for you. Don't forget to replace xxx.yyy, and rename xib file (if required)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>Icon.png</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>xxx.yyy.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainWindow</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you just want an empty info.plist file, then just select "New File..." on the "File" menu in XCode.

In the "New File" window you pick "Other" on the left hand and then "Property List" on the right hand.

Answer (score 4):

I had problem finding "Info.plist" file too, especially that some C++ test application target doesn't have "Info" tab, so modification in this file had to be done manually.

To find it:

1. Select project in project navigator
2. Select desired target (project can have multiple targets)
3. Select tab "build Settings"
4. Search for entry "Info.plist File". There you should find path of this file

Tested on Xcode 7.3.

In my case I had to "Allow Arbitrary Load" in "App Transport Security Settings" to restore insecure HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way: Proj Navigator --> Info --> add a line 'Scripting definition file name' 'Info.plist'.
Now you can find and edit the file.