# How change info.plist variables from another file?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'am building a webview integrated with Facebook SDK, and i want a separated file to modify the FacebookID inside info.plist. Help me pls!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to prepare a another info.plist file you would have to 
follow this link:- [How to regenerate an iPhone Xcode info.plist file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337403/how-to-regenerate-an-iphone-xcode-info-plist-file)
and after creating an info.plist file add the following code by right clicking the plist file and open it as a source editor and add the code there:-  this code must be before

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>fb{your-app-id}</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>{your-app-id}</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>{your-app-name}</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
  <string>{human-readable reason for photo access}</string>
```

i hope this will help you in creating the a seprate info.plist for your seprate facebook id

Comment: Ty man, but i need to do something different, in the place "{your-app-id}" i want to put a variable ${FACEBOOK_ID} where i can set for a another file in my webview.